# Get current user in a TagHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In a C# (ASP.NET Core) project, after login, the site must list a menu with a submenu according with permissions of the user.
This menu appear in all sites. Basically is a dashboard menu.

The content of this menu (submenus) are dynamically, according with user's permission.
So, I think in creating a TagHelper class, that get the current logged user, get the content that this user has permission, and create the content of submenu (somes `<ul>` and `<li>`).

I don't know if this is the best approach. I accept suggestions.

But, if this approach is OK to use, how I can get the current logged user on a TagHelper class?
I don't have a `HttpContext` on this class, only a `TagHelperContext`.

TagHelper:

```
public class UserContentTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public UserContentTagHelper(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagMode == TagMode.SelfClosing;

        // Error. HttpContext.User not avaliable
        var uid = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
    }
}
```

Normally to get the currently logged user, I use `HttpContext.User`, but this is avaliable only on Controller class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add an `IActionContextAccessor` parameter to your constructor. You can then get the HttpContext and its associated user with:

```
var user = actionAccessor.ActionContext.HttpContext.User;
var uid = _userManager.GetUserId(user);
```

You will also need to register the `IActionContextAccessor` in your ConfigureServices method of the Startup class:

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: worked! only need to configure the DI of IActionContextAccessor (`services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();`) and maybe it's a typo, but uid must be `var uid = _userManager.GetUserId(user);`